# Ejecutar dos comandos en la consola (windows)

Tags: windows, terminal

Quiero ejecutar dos comandos desde la consola/terminal de windows en una solo linea ( o instruccion ;)

En linux seria algo como `cd directory && ls` y ejecutaria estos comandos uno tras otro, como puedo conseguir este resultado pero en windows?

Comment: O no has probado lo que propones o tendrás que añadir los comandos

Comment: es que estoy desde linux, pero el codigo se va a ejecutar en un servidor con windows, por lo que quiero agregar un comando que sea multiplataforma o por lo menos darle varias opciones de dependencia del sistema operativo

Comment: Yo no conozco comandos ni scripts multiplataforma. Tendrás que probarlo con un win, por lo general funciona el &...

Comment: Como dice @hexadecimal, es totalmente válido hacer: `echo "1" > c:\Temp\1.txt & echo "2" > c:\Temp\2.txt & dir c:\Temp\*.txt & del c:\Temp\1.txt & del c:\Temp\2.txt & dir c:\Temp\*.txt`

Comment: Uhmm, gracias, y con `&&` tambien funciona ?

Comment: Eso ya depende del comando por lo general si (no sé en que parte de un bat no podría funcionar) pero en un vbs no se puede poner en cualquier lugar, tendrás que dedicarle su tiempo a los diferentes tipos de scripts en win y eso si no hay otras cosas más simples hablando de servers

Comment: solo para saber, ... `vbs`?

Comment: no se mucho sobre vbs, pero significa Visual Basic Scripts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He probado estos comandos en window `cd dir && dir` `cd dir ; dir` y funciona, o sea, supongo que puedas hacer lo que te propones separando los comandos con `;` o `&&`. El `;` los ejecuta todos uno tras otro y el `&&` los ejecuta mientras sean exitosos, es decir, si alguno falla los siguientes no son ejecutados.

Comment: Tambien puedes verificar y buscar mas aqui [http://foro.elhacker.net/windows/varios_comandos_cmd_en_una_lina-t294420.0.html;msg1458069]

Comment: Si es un vbs no puede incluir && en cualquier parte para unir "comandos"

Answer (score 0):

Una solución que podrías implementar es crear un batch, donde se encuentre todo el código que deseas que se ejecute. Si deseas hacer una prueba genera el archivo y luego llámalo desde la consola o solo bastaría con un doble click.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero sea una solución a lo que buscas, saludos.

Comment: Lo siento pero esto no es lo que busco, yo se que se podria hacer de esta forma, pero la situacion requiere que sea desde un solo comando :(

Answer (score 0):

Hola no se supongo que ya has podido encontrar la solución a tu pregunta, en el caso de que tu duda aun no se haya aclarado te la aclaro. El comando cd directory && ls tambien funiciona, por lo que veo quieres que el comando se dirija a un directorio que el usuario escriba y que luego se haga un listado de ese mismo directorio, pues el comando seria este: cd nombredeldirectorio && dir

cd nombredeldirectorio & dir

ojo habría que cambiar nombredeldirectorio por el nombre del directorio indicado. Espero haberte ayudado a ti a otros futuros usuarios que buscan la solución.